# Arc menu item style as like in tumblr app for Android

Tags: menu

Hi I am new in mobile app development. I found the menu of the app "Tumblr" very interesting. But I did not get any code for that kind of menu. All I have got is few codes for satellite menu in android. Please help me if some one knows how to create such kind of menu.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the complete demo code and explanation [here](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu).

Comment: But I want the menu like the app "Tumblr" not Arc or Ray Menu

Comment: Even I am looking for it. Any luck? I hope you are also referring to the latest menu which takes up the entire screen.